# How to get translated field using Twig tweak?

Tags: 8, theming

I use [twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) for rendering username on site this way:

username.html.twig:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for displaying a username.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - account: The full account information for the user.
 * - uid: The user ID, or zero if not a user. As used in anonymous comments.
 * - name: The user's name, sanitized, and optionally truncated.
 * - name_raw: The user's name, un-truncated.
 * - truncated: Whether the user's name was truncated.
 * - extra: Additional text to append to the user's name, sanitized.
 * - profile_access: Whether the current user has permission to access this
     users profile page.
 * - link_path: The path or URL of the user's profile page, home page,
 *   or other desired page to link to for more information about the user.
 * - homepage: (optional) The home page of the account, only set for non users.
 * - link_options: Options to set on the \Drupal\Core\Url object if linking the
 *   user's name to the user's page.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_username()
 */
#}    
{% if link_path -%}
  <a{{ attributes }}>{{ drupal_field('field_name', 'user', uid) }}{{ extra }}</a>
{%- else -%}
  <span{{ attributes }}>{{ drupal_field('field_name', 'user', uid) }}{{ extra }}</span>
{%- endif -%}
```

But this doesn't work with translation. How to get translated field?

4k4 answer this way:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_name', 'user', uid, user.langcode.value) }}
```

But I don't need language from session/url, not from user settings

Comment: Report that as a bug in that module. I don't really see why you would need that kind of template, you have account available to use which is the user entity. You can also use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_format_name_alter/8.5.x to alter the name anywhere that getDisplayName() is used, that will affect more places, including those that do not use the username template, for example because it is not in a HTML context. To get the translated user entity, you can use the same as I explained in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/255843/31

Comment: @berdir is it possible to retrieve current language form an entity?

Answer (score 1):

Try the language parameter:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_name', 'user', uid, user.langcode.value) }}
```

This was added to drupal_field() in this issue [Support drupal_field translatability](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak/issues/2833546).

For this to work the `user` entity needs to be available in your template.

Comment: This doesn't work. I need language from current page (session), not from user settings

Answer (score 0):

tried with: `{{ drupal_field('field_name', 'user', uid) | transliterate }}` ?

Comment: This doesn't work.